# Can I prevent 'Video paused' message in YouTube?

Tags: youtube

I use YouTube to listen to music while I work. I usually leave a playlist going while I work in other tabs or other programs altogether.

Sometimes, I have yet to determine what triggers it, YouTube stops the playback and presents me with this message:

[image: A prompt saying "video paused. continue watching?"]

Is it possible to deactivate this behavior? Is there an option hidden somewhere in the YouTube account that allows me to avoid this nuisance?

Answer (score 1):

There are third party extensions [like 'Continue Watching' for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-continue-watching/cnbpanpdoobkmlmgnapmlfcmgnaaiklc) that can solve this.

YouTube doesn't offer this functionality natively, likely because this popup is a cost saving measure of some sort.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone interested: there are extensions for it on Chrome and Firefox.

Chrome:
 https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/youtube-nonstop/nlkaejimjacpillmajjnopmpbkbnocid

Firefox:
https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/youtube-nonstop/